# Weird bug when getting long value from json on esp8266 (arduinoIDE)

Tags: json, parsing, arduino, long-integer, arduino-esp8266

Tldr; The problem was that the long type on the esp8266 is translated as a signed 32bit int which is much so small to hold the value. Using unsigned long long works. Longer explanation at the bottom.

I want to parse the JSON response from http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now and extract the "currentFileTime" field. 
As Hardware I am using an ESP-01.
Unfortunately I can extract all fields except for the one I need.

I am using the arduinoJSON library in Version 6. I used the https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/ to generate a code needed for deserialization. I tried to find anything in the docs indicating what cause this behaviour. It is expected behaviour for the parser to return the default value for a variable if the key is not present, which would be the 0 I am seeing, I even if I verify that the key is present with `jsonBuffer.containsKey("currentFileTime")` it still returns 0. 
I also tried to use a StaticJsonDocument with the same result.

```
long GetDateTime() {
  HTTPClient http;  //Object of class HTTPClient
  http.begin("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  //Check the returning code                                                                  
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    // Get the request response payload
    String payload = http.getString();
    const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(9) + 200;
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);

    // Just using this payload from the Arduino Assistant to test
    const char* json = "{\"$id\":\"1\",\"currentDateTime\":\"2019-05-25T07:40Z\",\"utcOffset\":\"00:00:00\",\"isDayLightSavingsTime\":false,\"dayOfTheWeek\":\"Saturday\",\"timeZoneName\":\"UTC\",\"currentFileTime\":132032436125212740,\"ordinalDate\":\"2019-145\",\"serviceResponse\":null}";

    deserializeJson(doc, json);

    const char* _id = doc["$id"]; // "1"
    const char* currentDateTime = doc["currentDateTime"]; // "2019-05-25T07:40Z"
    const char* utcOffset = doc["utcOffset"]; // "00:00:00"
    bool isDayLightSavingsTime = doc["isDayLightSavingsTime"]; // false
    const char* dayOfTheWeek = doc["dayOfTheWeek"]; // "Saturday"
    const char* timeZoneName = doc["timeZoneName"]; // "UTC"
    long currentFileTime = doc["currentFileTime"]; // 132032436125212740
    const char* ordinalDate = doc["ordinalDate"]; // "2019-145"
    Serial.println("What I want:");
    Serial.println(currentFileTime);
    Serial.println("The rest:");
    Serial.println(dayOfTheWeek);
    Serial.println(currentDateTime);
    Serial.println(utcOffset);
    Serial.println(isDayLightSavingsTime);
    Serial.println(timeZoneName);
    Serial.println(ordinalDate);

    if (doc.containsKey("currentFileTime")) {
      Serial.println("Yes currentFileTime is a key!");
      Serial.println(currentFileTime);
    } else {
      Serial.println("No currentFileTime is not a key!");
    }
    if (doc.containsKey("timeZoneName")) {
      Serial.println("Yes timeZoneName is a key!");
      Serial.println(timeZoneName);
    } else {
      Serial.println("No timeZoneName is not a key!");
    }

    return currentFileTime;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and on the Serial output I get:

```
What I want:
0
The rest:
Saturday
2019-05-25T07:40Z
00:00:00
0
UTC
2019-145
Yes currentFileTime is a key!
0
Yes timeZoneName is a key!
UTC
```

I expect that the "currentFileTime" gives me a value of 132032436125212740 but instead the default value of 0 is returned. 
Might this be a Problem with the long datatype on esp-01?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**:
Error search:
1. Casting the value to string did result in a correct output:

```
String currentFileTime = doc["currentFileTime"].as<String>(); // 132032436125212740
```

Ouput was something like 1.3e^17. So the value was in that field and the key wasn't the problem. 
2. [In the esp8266 c_types.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/c_types.h) I found out, that long is translated to a a signed int32 (max. Value:  [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)) which is much to small. 
3. Using unsigned long long which is a int 64 with a max value of 18446744073709551616 did do the trick
4. I tried to print the value with

```
Serial.println(currentFileTime);
```

But got the error:

```
call of overloaded 'println(long long unsigned int&)' is ambiguous
```

Apparently the Serial library can only handle 32 bit values so I followed [this](https://yoursunny.com/t/2018/PriUint64/) guide and installed [this](https://github.com/yoursunny/PriUint64/blob/master/src/PriUint64.h) library (copy pasted the whole file in my header). And I could finally print the value!
Hope this might help.